# Mixing AppleScript and bash for a simple url opener

Tags: bash, applescript

I have a large list of urls (urls.txt) \n separated, all valid RFC https urls in the usual format of https://example.com/path/path/path/file.jpg

All urls seem to be TLS/SSL
All urls seem to be jpg or gif file
All urls have manually been tested to work in Safari.

I want to read in the url's, loop through them, assign it to a variable as it passes through the loop, then I was thinking about using a heretic to shove in some applescript to run the `open` ( I am on mac OS X obviously :) ) command, which seems to nicely default url's to my default browser and also given a window with content in it, given my Safari preferences, a new tab will be fired open.  So `open` as a raw command does just what I want.

For some reason, the second I step outside of bash into the heredoc, things get messy and stop working.  Applescript is a strange little cousin of that really strange kid in school.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Fire open a new tab for each url on a line in a file.\n"

urls=$(cat urls.txt)

for i in $urls; do
    echo "Opening URL item: $i"

#heredocs are nice
/usr/bin/osascript << EOF
set the_url to quoted form of $i
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Safari.app" "$the_url"
EOF

done
exit 0
```

Here is a small snip of the error output that is sent back to the shell:
$./go
Fire open a new tab for each url on a line in a file.

Opening URL item: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/340087/drops/12.22.14/bbq-galore-and-more-59-082636.jpg
30:36: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
Opening URL item: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/340087/drops/12.22.14/card-88-082636.jpg
30:36: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
Opening URL item: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/340087/drops/12.22.14/catalog-c2-082636.jpg
30:36: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
Opening URL item: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/340087/drops/12.22.14/chris-360overlibrary-e9-082636.gif
30:36: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)

The colon can't go afer... error I am guessing is the colon in the url, since there aren't any others in the code that could cause the error in that location.  I know there has to be a way to make it work, and I suspect it has to do with quoting.  Perhaps I ned to add open Safari.app quoted form of $i or something like that.

Thank you for any help.  Hopefully I can add to the top of the script
echo "About to open $( wc -l urls.txt ) new tabs in Safari, are you ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla AppleScript:

```
set errorLog to {}
set urlText to read POSIX file "/Users/you/Desktop/urls.txt" as «class utf8»
set urlList to paragraphs of urlText
repeat with aUrl in urlList
    try
        open location aUrl
    on error
        set end of errorLog to aUrl
    end try
end repeat
```

EDIT

```
set myDelay to 0.2
set errorLog to {}
set urlText to read POSIX file "/Users/you/Desktop/urls.txt" as «class utf8»
set urlList to paragraphs of urlText
repeat with aUrl in urlList
    set aUrl to contents of aUrl
    if aUrl ≠ "" then
        try
            tell application "Safari" to open location aUrl
            -- open location aUrl
            delay myDelay
        on error
            set end of errorLog to aUrl
        end try
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Nice, although with Safari as the default browser, this _also fails partially due to timing issues_ (Safari 8.0.2), as with the `open` utility, albeit _quietly_. With 16 input URLs, typically only 4 tabs open on my machine, and no errors are reported. The curious part is that it _does_ work correctly if you use `tell application "Safari" to open location aUrl`, i.e., if you target Safari explicitly (which may or may not be desired).

Comment: Also, a quibble: If the input file ends with `\n` - which is typical - `urlList` will have an empty trailing element.

Comment: Open location belongs to Standard Additions, not Safari. That is curious.

Comment: I spent some time over the last day researching, it looks like we are not the only ones to fall into this trap of Safari being silly,  The method of passing an arg list to the open command was so perfect, too bad it didn't work.  If I am going to have to toss in a repeat loop, I may as well stick native on use AppleScript on this little script.  Here is a link to how the Daring FireBall guy solves it, which is similar in that he had issues, but his approach is more convoluted in my opinion: http://daringfireball.net/2003/02/save_and_restore_safari_urls

Answer (score 3):

`open` is a *Unix* executable, just call it directly from your bash script - no need to get AppleScript involved. (In fact, you'd need to use `do shell script` in AppleScript to call it).

Here's a more robust version of your script, which, unfortunately, *necessitates a clumsy workaround in order to work reliably with many URLs (as of OSX 10.10.1 / Safari 8.0.2)*:

The code should work both when targeting the default browser (`open <url>`) and when targeting Safari explicitly, as below (`open -a Safari <url>`).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Open a new tab for each url on a line in a file.\n"

# Read all URLs into bash _array_ variable `urls`.
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a urls < urls.txt

# Simple confirmation prompt.
echo "About to open ${#urls[@]} new tabs in Safari. Press Return to continue, ^C to abort."
read

# Open the URLs *one by one*, with a *sleep-and-retry* mechanism - see background
# below.     

timeout=3 # in seconds
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do # Loop over all URLs.
  SECONDS=0 # Start timing.
  while true; do # Keep trying to open the URL until success or timeout.
    # Omit '-a Safari' to open with the _default_ browser.
    # Add '-F' to start Safari without restoring previously open windows.
    # (If it's already open, the tabs will still be added.)
    # Without -F, the tabs are always added to the front window's 
    # existing tabs (which may stem from restoring a previous session).
    open -a Safari "$url" 2>/dev/null && break  # OK
    if (( SECONDS >= timeout )); then # Time out eventually.
      echo "WARNING: failed to open $url within $timeout second$( ((timeout == 1 )) || printf 's' )." >&2
      break # Proceed to next URL.
    fi
    # Sleep a little, then retry opening this URL.
    sleep 0.2
  done
done
```

Sadly, the following does NOT work *reliably* on OSX 10.10.1 / Safari 8.0.2,
even though it SHOULD:

```
open -a "Safari" "${urls[@]}"  # pass all URLs at once.
```

**Safari apparently gets too busy opening tabs so that later URLs often
fail to open**, resulting in nondescript `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Safari.app with error -1712 for the URLs ...` errors.
Given that `open` is by default *asynchronous*, there's no good reason for this to happen (Safari should just queue the requests and process them sequentially), so I've submitted a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com  - I encourage everyone to do the same.

The - clumsy - workaround is a **one-by-one approach to opening**,
with a **sleep-then-retry mechanism**. Sadly, there's nothing in 
Safari's AppleScript dictionary that would allow us to check Safari's
ready state.

Note, however, that even with this one-by-one approach, **loading
is asynchronous**, so the **tabs are NOT guaranteed to appear in the order
they were specified**.

Also, it seems that **existing tabs with the same URL are *sometimes* reused**,
whereas a new tab is opened other times - couldn't find any rhyme or
reason behind this.

---

The situation in **AppleScript** is similar, though not identical (assumes Safari 8.0.2 as the default browser):

- Using just `open location <url>` *without an application context* (to target the default browser) partially fails too, and does so *quietly*.

  - e.g., with Safari initially not running and 16 input URLs, only 4 tabs end up open on my machine - no errors are reported
- Curiously, using `tell application Safari to open location <url>` - i.e., *explicitly targeting Safari* - *does* seem to work properly.

Thus, the *only way to directly avoid the timing issues as of Safari 8.0.2 is* to *explicitly target Safari via AppleScript* - which may or may not be acceptable; here's a snippet that replaces the `for` loop in the code above:

```
open -a Safari
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
  osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\" to open location \"$url\""
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test it out now. though to me, everything looks perfect.  I want to stage it into github first, just because I am learning git hub and don't want it to get to strange as a initial committee

Comment: Did you actually get 16 tabs open?  I get a subset.  I put in the urls.txt file "open " leading each url and copied all those, pasted them into the terminal and pressed return and got 16 tabs, even though some pages are 404 or dead, I got 16, or right about there.  I think the bash is too fast, any way to put a sleeper in there somewhere.  since you are not using a traditional loop, I don't know how to iterate after each item.

Comment: Made a new simpler list, one in which I know all the urls work, all but one were non SSL/TLS, they all opened, but: https://gist.github.com/5c0tt/91b7bfe822b35ca1a19f

Comment: @Scott: I had only tested with _2_ URLs, so thanks for detecting the problem. I've rewritten the answer to address this issue; unfortunately, the required workaround isn't pretty. The updated answer now also contains a regular bash loop that iterates over the URLs (the elements of the `urls` array).

Comment: @Scott: If targeting Safari explicitly is OK, consider the simpler AppleScript-based workaround I've added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I marked the other post as the answer, though I want to be clear, this is just as good in my opinion, it just didn't happen to work out for this particular case.  Thanks for such great help to this from all of you.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful feedback, @Scott. I'm glad you found a solution.